# Подобрать синоним к "время основания города"

Tags: синонимы

Точное время основания города неизвестно.

Подобрать синоним к слову основания.

Заложения? Коробит слух)

Answer (score 1):

При описании истории городов обычно говорят об основании или возникновении города.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно говорят или о *первом упоминании*, или о *возникновении первого поселения*. О заложении или основании города, не зная точной даты и обстоятельств, сказать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

> Заложения? Коробит слух)

Можно и "заложения".

См., [например, здесь](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22).